# Display a user webcam over multiplayer session on a wall in the middle of a level?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, unreal-4, unreal, materials

With the media framework, it’s now quite easy to use webcam or phone camera footage directly in the game.
Is there also a way to share this footage in a multiplayer game? So player A can see the footage of player B and so on?

I've been trying to make something that lets me broadcast the webcam from one player to everyone in a level using a material, but there doesnt seem to be anything that let's this replicate? Am I missing something or do I need a fancy plugin that does this for me?

Comment: Unreal's replication systems are likely set up to transmit low bandwidth information like inputs and game events happening a few dozen times a second. Transmitting pixel colours for millions of pixels at a realtime framerate is orders of magnitude more data, demanding specialized video compression and streaming systems more like you find in video conferencing apps like Zoom. It's possible, but I'd expect you'd need to go beyond the built-in features to get it. I'm posting this as a comment because I don't have direct experience in how to solve this in Unreal to be able to guide you in detail.

Comment: Honestly, i hadnt thought of it like that. I guess it'd be mandatory to find a pre-existing video call library and integrate it into UE4/5 via C++ then try to hack something together using built in tools.